Problems about displaying Immersive Space
I'm working on my project to display an immersive space of Earth's Orbits. I use the method from Apple's Documentation to display an immersive space but it doesn't show up.
Here's the logic:
The user will be first directed into this view:
struct TransitionOrbit: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ImmersiveButton(immersiveSpaceID: "orbits")
    }
}

The logic of button is here:
struct ImmersiveButton: View {
    let immersiveSpaceID: String 

    @Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) private var openImmersiveSpace
    @Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) private var dismissImmersiveSpace

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Open Immersive Space") {
                Task {
                    await openImmersiveSpace(id: immersiveSpaceID)
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .padding()

            Button("Dismiss Immersive Space") {
                Task {
                    await dismissImmersiveSpace()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

And this view is supposed to be shown after the click
struct OrbitsIntro: View {

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            // Load the Reality Composer Pro scene
            if let earthScene = try? await Entity(named: "EarthScene", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                content.add(earthScene)
            }
        }
    }
}

However, when I click the button, nothing is appeared. I've checked my App file
@main
struct HelloWorldApp: App {
    @State private var currentStyle: ImmersionStyle = .full

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TitlePage()
        }
        
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "orbits") {
            OrbitsIntro()
        }
    }
}

The 3D content can be displayed when I look directly into the preview(not immersive), however it just can't show when using the logic above. Additionally, when I direct previews the content from Xcode it appears to be restricted within an area and everything outside of it vanished. The program can be built successfully and I've completely out of ideas how this happens.
